# Defining a control template for a rectangle in XAML

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, rectangles

In my current project, I have this XAML file where I define the visual style that must be applied to different types of custom widgets.

For example, the style for a 'DirectLineButton' (a custom class that inherits from WPF's Button) is as follows:

```
    <Style x:Key="DirectLineButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type View:DirectLineButton}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="MyBorder"  
               CornerRadius="2" 
               BorderThickness="2"
               Background="Gold"
               BorderBrush="Gray">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineAvailable">
            <Setter TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineIdle">
            <Setter  TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineBusy">
            <Setter  TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineCalled">
            <Setter  TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, I need to replicate this idea by defining the style for a Rectangle. Unfortunately, WPF flags an error message when I try to define a ControlTemplate for a rectangle, can you suggest a workaround for this? See the code below of what I'm trying to attempt:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyRectangleTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Border x:Name="MyBorder"  
               CornerRadius="2" 
               BorderThickness="2"
               Background="Gold"
               BorderBrush="Gray">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineAvailable">
            <Setter TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineIdle">
            <Setter  TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Silver"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineBusy">
            <Setter  TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="View:DirectLineButton.State" Value="DirectLineCalled">
            <Setter  TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you will have to do it with Border only.Controls that inherits FrameworkElement only  can have Template . But Rectangle , Line etc are lighter versions they inherits only UIElement not FrameworkElement.I hope this will help. Conclusion: Rectange do not have Template property

Comment: Actually, `Rectangle` is derived from `FrameworkElement`. Control templates are only available for...controls :)

Comment: yes my bad , i got bit confused, its just fault of VisualStudio that provide us so much info that we dont have to remember each and everything.

Comment: @ethicallogics : could you please edit your answer to give the right heritance scheme ?  ( i delete this comment once you've done it )

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a control template for a `Rectangle`, since it's not a control, but a `Shape`. You can only define a control template for classes derived from `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

You should
   1) use a `Style` (not a `ControlTemplate`) to have rounded borders.
   2) Use a `Trigger` inside your style.

The following Xaml should get you closer from your goal :

```
 <Style x:Key="MyRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
       <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
       <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
       <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
       <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>

       <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="2" />
       <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="2" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DirectLineState}" 
                        Value="{x:Static l:DLS.Available}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gold"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DirectLineState}" 
                        Value="{x:Static l:DLS.Idle}" >
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Silver"/>
    </DataTrigger >
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DirectLineState}"                            
                         Value="{x:Static l:DLS.Available}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
    </DataTrigger >
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DirectLineState}" 
                         Value="{x:Static l:DLS.Called}">
        <Setter  Property="Fill" Value="LightBlue"/>
    </DataTrigger >
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(notice that :
1)  i changed the key for "MyRectangleStyle".
2)  If you want this `Style` to be the default `Style`, do not give it a `Key`, but just a `TargetType`...
3) ...OR set the `Key` to `"{x:Type Rectangle}"`. msdn seems to prefer that way.
btw : shouldn't you be using DataTriggers on public properties instead of Triggers ? but i don't know the whole architecture of your application. )

Rq : for the code above to work, you need :
1) a public proprety called DirectLineState raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` on change.
2) an `enum` called DLS defined in a separate file (like a class) in your project
3) you need "l" to be your project NameSpace.

```
     <xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MyProjectNameSpace" >
```

4) Assign `Style` and set proper `DataContext` for the `Rectangle`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your approach and the correct background colour is being set at start-up based on the initial state. However, when I change the associated value to the component's "State" dependency property, the background colour remains the same (i.e., it doesn't get updated). It seems to me that I'm missing one last step in here, any ideas?

Comment: 1) you have to check that the DataContext is the right one. To be sure for your test just give your rectangle a name and assign DataContext in window constructor. 2) as i said i don't understand how your button template works : you should be using DataTrigers. I updated my answer, and as it is now it works (i tested).

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late reply! My original post was actually made on behalf of a colleague who was experiencing the problem. He finally solved it by assembling the custom control using buttons instead of rectangles. Once again, thanks for your help!